# Pass log function to Promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

For a Node library, I want to be able to pass a log function to a function that returns a Promise. By default, the logger would be `console.log`, but might be replaced by something else, depending on the use case.

```
// define custom logger
const opts = {
    log: console.log,
    error: console.error
};

const spawnPromise = (cmd, args, opts) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const child = spawn(cmd, args, opts);

    child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      // use custom log function
      opts.log(stringify(data));
    });

    child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      // use custom error function
      opts.error(stringify(data));
    });

    child.on('close', (code) => {
      if (code === 0) {
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    });
  });
};
```

This results in the following error:

```
Uncaught Exception: test.js
  TypeError: opts.log is not a function
    Socket.<anonymous>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you calling `spawnPromise`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `opts` within `spawnPromise` is **not** the `opts` you've declared above it, it's the parameter you've declared for `spawnPromise` here:

```
const spawnPromise = (cmd, args, opts) => {
// ------------------------------^^^^
```

That parameter shadows the module-global. `spawnPromise` will use what you pass it, not the module global. If you want to use the module global, change the name of it or the parameter.

Perhaps (see `<===` comments):

```
// define custom logger
const defaultOpts = {                          // <=== Change name
    log: console.log,
    error: console.error
};

const spawnPromise = (cmd, args, opts) => {
  opts = Object.assign({}, defaultOpts, opts); // <=== Expand with defaults
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const child = spawn(cmd, args, opts);

    child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      // use custom log function
      opts.log(stringify(data));
    });

    child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      // use custom error function
      opts.error(stringify(data));
    });

    child.on('close', (code) => {
      if (code === 0) {
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Note that `Object.assign` will ignore it if `opts` is `null` or `undefined` (rather than causing an error).

With a [Stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread), that `Object.assign` could use spread instead:

```
  opts = {...defaultOpts, ...opts};
```

In its current form, it's also okay with `opts` being `null` or `undefined`. But again, spread properties are just Stage 3 at present.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified that here, but you're probably calling `spawnPromise` with the `opts` argument as something other than the `opts` you are defining at the top, or passing nothing at all to that argument in your function call, which will make it undefined.

It might be a good idea for a standalone module to throw a specific error when `opts.log` is not a function, or to handle it in some other explicit way.